# Add date filter to post

Tags: php, mysql

I have this code and it is for showing most read article in my site what i need is to make it display most read article in past two day not in the whole article

```
<div id="content_2" class="content">
    <ul>
 <?php

$mysm=mysql_query("select id,n_id,title,image,status,date from news where   viwe > 0 and status=1  order by viwe DESC  LIMIT 0, 7  ");
while($mydm=mysql_fetch_object($mysm)){?>
        <li class="">
```

Comment: And what is your question? http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: include where date between clause also ....

Comment: maybe the question is are my columns spelled wrong, like `viwe`, who knows

Answer (score 0):

Take current date, subtract it with 2 days and compare to the date column.

Below query will return posts viewed in past 2 days:

```
select id,n_id,title,image,status,date
from news where viwe > 0 and status=1
and date >= (CURDATE() - INTERVAL 2 DAY) order by viwe DESC  LIMIT 0, 7;
```